# Using ctypes to pass around struct pointers

Tags: python, c, ctypes

So what I have done so far is build a small ctypes and python code which does the following:

- Python calls a C function with a pointer to a void pointer as the argument.
- The C code creates a struct of type `ReturnStruct` and instantiates it and its data members then sets the pointer passed in by python to point to this struct.
- Python calls another C function multiple times to increment some values.
- Python then checks the values.
- Python calls a C function to deallocate the struct pointer.

So far I have the first 3 stages working but I am having problems with the last two parts. Here is the C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include "runSolver.h"

#define SMB_MAX_DATA_SIZE 16

typedef struct testStruct {
  double *x[11];
  double *u[10];
} Test;

typedef struct returnStruct_t {
  Test* vars;
} ReturnStruct;

void initalize_returnStruct(void** returnStruct){
  ReturnStruct* new_returnStruct = (ReturnStruct *)malloc(sizeof(ReturnStruct));
  Test* varsStruct = (Test*)malloc(sizeof(Test)*3);

  int dataSize = 5;
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    int x;
    for(x = 0; x < 11; x++)
      varsStruct[i].x[x] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*5);    
    for(x = 0; x < 10; x++)
      varsStruct[i].u[x] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*5);    
  }
  new_returnStruct->vars = varsStruct;
  *returnStruct = new_returnStruct;
}

void free_returnStruct(void* data){
  ReturnStruct* returnStruct = data;
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    int x;
    for(x = 1; x < 11; x++) 
      free(returnStruct->vars[i].x[x]);
    for(x = 0; x < 10; x++)
      free(returnStruct->vars[i].u[x]);
  }
  free(returnStruct->vars);
  free(returnStruct);
}

void parallelSolver(void* data){

  ReturnStruct* VarsArray = data;

  fprintf(stderr, " This is the value: %f \n", VarsArray->vars[0].x[0][0]);  
  fprintf(stderr, " This is the value: %f \n", VarsArray->vars[0].x[10][4]);
  fprintf(stderr, " This is the value: %f \n", VarsArray->vars[0].u[0][0]);
  fprintf(stderr, " This is the value: %f \n", VarsArray->vars[0].u[9][2]);

  VarsArray->vars[0].x[0][0] += 20.0;
  VarsArray->vars[0].x[10][4] += 203.0;
  VarsArray->vars[0].u[0][0] += 202.0;
  VarsArray->vars[0].u[9][2] += 202.0;                         
}
```

And here is the python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import ctypes as ct

numOpt = 3

class vars_t(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("u", ct.POINTER(ct.c_double*10)),
                    ("x", ct.POINTER(ct.c_double*11))]

class returnStruct_t(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("vars", vars_t*numOpt)]

runSolver = ct.CDLL('./runSolverParallel.so')

returnStructPointer = ct.POINTER(returnStruct_t)
runSolver.parallelSolver.argtypes = [ct.c_void_p()]

varsd = ct.c_void_p()
runSolver.initalize_returnStruct(ct.byref(varsd)) 

runSolver.parallelSolver(varsd)
runSolver.parallelSolver(varsd)
runSolver.parallelSolver(varsd)
runSolver.parallelSolver(varsd)

varsdb = ct.cast(varsd, returnStruct_t)

print(varsdb.contents.vars[0].x[0][0])

runSolver.free_returnStruct(varsd)
```

The code runs fine till I get to these three lines:

```
varsdb = ct.cast(varsd, returnStruct_t)

print(varsdb.contents.vars[0].x[0][0])

runSolver.free_returnStruct(varsd)
```

All of which create seg faults. Any advice on how to get this working properly would appreciated!

The errors look like this:

```
Starting program: /usr/bin/python UserDefinedCode.py
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
 This is the value: 0.000000 
 This is the value: 0.000000 
 This is the value: 0.000000 
 This is the value: 0.000000 
 This is the value: 20.000000 
 This is the value: 203.000000 
 This is the value: 202.000000 
 This is the value: 202.000000 
 This is the value: 40.000000 
 This is the value: 406.000000 
 This is the value: 404.000000 
 This is the value: 404.000000 
 This is the value: 60.000000 
 This is the value: 609.000000 
 This is the value: 606.000000 
 This is the value: 606.000000 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff33795d4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007ffff33795d4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
#1  0x00007ffff3386ea4 in ffi_call_unix64 () from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
#2  0x00007ffff33868c5 in ffi_call () from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
#3  0x00007ffff33772c2 in _ctypes_callproc () from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
#4  0x00007ffff3377aa2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
#5  0x00000000004d91b6 in PyObject_Call ()
#6  0x000000000054c0da in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#7  0x000000000054c272 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#8  0x0000000000575d92 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#9  0x00000000004c1352 in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags ()
#10 0x00000000004c754f in Py_Main ()
#11 0x00007ffff68cb76d in __libc_start_main (main=0x41ba10 <main>, argc=2, ubp_av=0x7fffffffe1d8, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffe1c8)
    at libc-start.c:226
#12 0x000000000041ba41 in _start ()
```

Comment: Can you strip this down to a smaller [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that doesn't do a bunch of irrelevant stuff, doesn't require `scipy`, etc.? That would make it much easier to debug.

Comment: Also, when I run this, I get every other number being something like `26815615859885194199148049996411692254958731641184786755447122887443528060147093953603748596333806855380063716372972101707507765623893139892867298012168192.000000`. Are you sure the C code is correct?

Comment: I just noticed that too but if I changed `x[10][4]` to `x[10][3]` in both instances it started working again. Not sure whats going on there.

Comment: `ct.cast(varsd, returnStruct_t)` is almost certainly going to segfault. It's like doing `returnStruct_t = *(returnStruct_t *)(&varsd)`. You probably wanted `ct.cast(varsd, returnStructPointer)`?

Comment: Well, if your C code isn't correct and is probably printing out uninitialized memory or something, it's hardly surprising that calling it from `ctypes` segfaults. Have you tried calling the same thing from a plain old C driver program?

Comment: Meanwhile, by running in the debugger: the cast does indeed segfault nearly 100% of the time. If I fix that, it segfaults later—`varsdb.contents.vars[0].x[0]` evaluates fine, but `varsdb.contents.vars[0].x[0][0]` crashes.

Comment: Interesting. After fixing the cast issue `varsdb.contents.vars[0].x[0][0]` works for me it just does not provide the value I would expect. I am going to test the code with a C driver really quick. Thanks!

Comment: On my Mac, if I compile the so with `clang` (Apple's build) with no options, it works exactly 50% of the time. If I compile with `gcc47 -O0` (Homebrew build), it crashes every time. With `gcc47 -O2`, it crashed the first time but never crashed again. So… just because it works for you once doesn't mean it's correct.

Comment: I found another problem: your `Struct` is wrong. See my answer; I've explained everything I found, but I don't know if that's everything that's actually wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You have at least four problems here (actually, five, but one isn't relevant).

The line that was (usually) causing your segfault is this:

```
varsdb = ct.cast(varsd, returnStruct_t)
```

This is because you're trying to cast a `void *` to a `returnStruct_t`, rather than to a `returnStruct_t *`. Since a `returnStruct_t` is much larger than a pointer, there's a good chance this will run off the end of an allocated page. Even if it doesn't segfault, it's giving you garbage values. It's equivalent to this C code:

```
returnStruct_t varsdb = *(returnStruct_t *)(&varsd);
```

What you wanted was the equivalent of:

```
returnStruct_t *varsdb = (returnStruct_t *)(varsd);
```

In other words:

```
varsdb = ct.cast(varsd, returnStructPointer)
```

---

After fixing that, I often, but not always, still get a segfault later, on trying to access `varsdb.contents.vars[0].x[0][0]` (`varsdb.contents.vars[0].x[0]` itself is always safe).

The next problem is that you haven't defined your struct properly. Here's the C:

```
typedef struct testStruct {
  double *x[11];
  double *u[10];
} Test;
```

And here's the Python:

```
class vars_t(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("u", ct.POINTER(ct.c_double*10)),
                    ("x", ct.POINTER(ct.c_double*11))]
```

You've mixed up `u` and `x`. So, what you're calling `x`, and treating as an array of 11 doubles, is actually `u`, an array of 10 doubles. So every time you touch x[10], you're going past the end of the array.

---

After fixing that one too, I get garbage values printed out. With the `clang` build, it's always close to `6.92987533417e-310`.

I think this one is purely in the C code. I often get garbage numbers printed out from those `x[10][4]` and `u[9][2]` lines in C. Again, with the same build, I get about an equal mix of reasonable values, numbers like `26815615859885194199148049996411692254958731641184786755447122887443528060147093953603748596333806855380063716372972101707507765623893139892867298012168192.000000` for both, and reasonable values for the former but `nan` for the latter.

And when I run a simple C driver under `valgrind`, every fourth `fprintf` I get this:

```
==85323== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
```

So you've presumably got an off-by-one error in your allocation or initialization code in C, and you sometimes but not always get away with it.

---

Also, these aren't the same type:

```
typedef struct returnStruct_t {
  Test* vars;
} ReturnStruct;

class returnStruct_t(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("vars", vars_t*numOpt)]
```

The former is a single pointer long, and that pointer points at an array of `Test` objects. The latter is 3 `Test` objects. So, once again, you're trying to read a pointer to something as a value of that type, and here you're going way past the end of the allocated value.

After fixing that, I no longer get any crashes, and I get reasonable final values like `80.0` even when I get the garbage printouts along the way. But of course I still get those garbage printouts along the way, and valgrind is still complaining, so obviously this still isn't the last problem.

---

You've also got an obvious leak in your code—which isn't directly relevant to the problem, but it's a good sign that you've probably got similar errors elsewhere. You allocate the `x` arrays like this:

```
for(x = 0; x < 11; x++)
  varsStruct[i].x[x] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*5);
```

… then free them like this:

```
for(x = 1; x < 11; x++) 
  free(returnStruct->vars[i].x[x]);
```

So `x[0]` never gets freed.

Comment: Thanks this was super helpful! Good catch on the wrong indices when I free the array. I also realized my struct members were out of order and fixed them. I am no long getting any segfaults or garbage numbers unless i go out of the specified range. However, when i try to print out any of the values after casting them to `varsdb` I am still not getting any of the numbers I would expect. Guess I will keep playing with it. Thanks for putting me on the right track!